# Can you form a temporary nonprofit?

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, oregon, non-profit

Can you start a 501c3 organization to complete a project, collect donations, do the project, donate all leftover money to another 501c3 with similar goals, then dissolve the organization? It would exist for a year at the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Getting all of the 501(c)(3) recognition paperwork processed in that time frame could be challenging, but there is nothing that requires a 501(c)(3) to have an infinite intended duration.